# Within Exchange server or elsewhere in the microsoft environment is it possible to extract email signatures>

Tags: exchange-server

Is it possible to extract email signatures in use in an exchange environment from all mailboxes ? I was thinking it could be given an org wide signature can be set.
If its not possible is it possible to flag emails that meet a particular set of conditions like have a signature that contains a phrase ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have an on-prem Exchange environment, you can get the mailbox signature for a mailbox with the Get-MailboxMessageConfiguration command and set the mailbox signature with the Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration. This is only the signature available through the webmail (Outlook on the web) though.
The signature used in the desktop Outlook is saved locally in the user profile and not on Exchange itself.

I would recommend a third party solution for an on-prem solution. There are multiple providers of such services available. CodeTwo is one example of a provider that offers such solutions.

If you are running Exchange Online, it's possible to create organization wide signatures and disclaimers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/create-signatures-and-disclaimers?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think all users use the webmail client and I doubt I'll get approval for 3rd party tools. Is it possible for exchange rules to flag emails that have a particular structure? I'm thinking there must be a way given the org wide signature needs to know where to start its contents

Comment: I’m not aware of a method. If you manage the end user Windows computers or if they are domain joined, you could extract the signature from the user profile. But that is a rather nasty route.